# PHP - how to pass parameters to a PHP class from javascript and return the response back to js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, class

I'm trying to use a PHP Class in conjunction with javascript, but I need to modify the class to be able to pass it a parameter, and since I'm not too familiar with PHP, I'm not sure how to do this. This is the class, below - as you can see it uses a static variable $site, but I want to be able to pass the site variable in. I also want to be able to return the data. Anyone know how to do this?

```
<?php
/**
 * Makes a request to AWIS for site info.
 */
class UrlInfo {

    protected static $ActionName        = 'UrlInfo';
    protected static $ResponseGroupName = 'Rank,LinksInCount';
    protected static $ServiceHost      = 'awis.amazonaws.com';
    protected static $NumReturn         = 10;
    protected static $StartNum          = 1;
    protected static $SigVersion        = '2';
    protected static $HashAlgorithm     = 'HmacSHA256';

    public function UrlInfo($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey, $site) {
        $this->accessKeyId = $accessKeyId;
        $this->secretAccessKey = $secretAccessKey;
        $this->site = $site;
    }

    /**
     * Get site info from AWIS.
     */ 
    public function getUrlInfo() {
        $queryParams = $this->buildQueryParams();
        $sig = $this->generateSignature($queryParams);
        $url = 'http://' . self::$ServiceHost . '/?' . $queryParams . '&Signature=' . $sig;
        echo "\nURL: " . $url . "<br/>";
        $ret = self::makeRequest($url);
        echo "\nResults for " . $this->site .":\n\n";
        self::parseResponse($ret);
    }

    /**
     * Builds current ISO8601 timestamp.
     */
    protected static function getTimestamp() {
        return gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
    }

    /**
     * Builds query parameters for the request to AWIS.
     * Parameter names will be in alphabetical order and
     * parameter values will be urlencoded per RFC 3986.
     * @return String query parameters for the request
     */
    protected function buildQueryParams() {
        $params = array(
            'Action'            => self::$ActionName,
            'ResponseGroup'     => self::$ResponseGroupName,
            'AWSAccessKeyId'    => $this->accessKeyId,
            'Timestamp'         => self::getTimestamp(),
            'Count'             => self::$NumReturn,
            'Start'             => self::$StartNum,
            'SignatureVersion'  => self::$SigVersion,
            'SignatureMethod'   => self::$HashAlgorithm,
            'Url'               => $this->site
        );
        ksort($params);
        $keyvalue = array();
        foreach($params as $k => $v) {
            $keyvalue[] = $k . '=' . rawurlencode($v);
        }
        $keyImplode = implode('&',$keyvalue);
        return implode('&',$keyvalue);  
    }

    /**
     * Makes request to AWIS
     * @param String $url   URL to make request to
     * @return String       Result of request
     */
    protected static function makeRequest($url) {
        /*echo "\nMaking request to:\n$url\n";*/
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Parses XML response from AWIS and displays selected data
     * @param String $response    xml response from AWIS
     */
    public static function parseResponse($response) {
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response,null,false,
                                    'http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11');
        if($xml->count() && $xml->Response->UrlInfoResult->Alexa->count()) {
            $info = $xml->Response->UrlInfoResult->Alexa;
            $nice_array = array(
                'Links In Count' => $info->ContentData->LinksInCount,
                'Rank'           => $info->TrafficData->Rank
            );
        }
        foreach($nice_array as $k => $v) {
            echo $k . ': ' . $v ."\n";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates an HMAC signature per RFC 2104.
     *
     * @param String $url       URL to use in createing signature
     */
    protected function generateSignature($url) {
        $sign = "GET\n" . strtolower(self::$ServiceHost) . "\n/\n". $url;
        echo "String to sign: \n" . $sign . "\n";
        $sigHMAC = hash_hmac('sha256', $sign, $this->secretAccessKey, true);
        echo "<br/>HMAC: " . $sigHMAC;
        $sig64 = base64_encode($sigHMAC);
        echo "<br/>BASE64: " . $sig64 . "<br/>";
        $sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $sign, $this->secretAccessKey, true));
        echo "<br/>ENCODED URL: " . rawurlencode($sig) ."<br/>";
        return rawurlencode($sig);
    }

}

/*if (count($argv) < 4) {
    echo "Usage: $argv[0] ACCESS_KEY_ID SECRET_ACCESS_KEY site\n";
    exit(-1);
}
else {
    $accessKeyId = $argv[1];
    $secretAccessKey = $argv[2];
    $site = $argv[3];
}*/

$accessKeyId = "AKIAJA664T37BDNPSXXX";
$secretAccessKey = "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"; 
$site = "http://site.com";

$urlInfo = new UrlInfo($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey, $site);
$urlInfo->getUrlInfo();

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that you have to modify the class. Just build yourself a PHP-script you cann pass the variables from your JS to, and which generates JSON. E.g.:

```
<?php
    $data = array();
    if ($_GET['ONE_PARAM'])
    {
        $url = new UrlInfo();
        $data = $url->YOUR_METHOD($_GET['ONE_PARAM']);
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo(json_encode($data));
?>
```

Then you pass your JS-variables via AJAX to your PHP-script, and read the response from there.

Answer (score 0):

You never define the class variables that you use in your constructor. You need to declare them in your class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Makes a request to AWIS for site info.
 */
class UrlInfo {

    protected static $ActionName        = 'UrlInfo';
    protected static $ResponseGroupName = 'Rank,LinksInCount';
    protected static $ServiceHost      = 'awis.amazonaws.com';
    protected static $NumReturn         = 10;
    protected static $StartNum          = 1;
    protected static $SigVersion        = '2';
    protected static $HashAlgorithm     = 'HmacSHA256';

    // Add your public class variables here
    public $accessKeyId;
    public $secretAccessKey;
    public $site;

    public function UrlInfo($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey, $site) {
        $this->accessKeyId = $accessKeyId;
        $this->secretAccessKey = $secretAccessKey;
        $this->site = $site;
    }
```